# Understanding overloading plus function

Tags: function, kotlin, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm following a kotlin overloading tutorial [here](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/operator-overloading) and failing to understand this example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
    val p1 = Point(3, -8) 
    val p2 = Point(2, 9) 
    var sum = Point() 
    sum = p1 + p2 
    println("sum = (${sum.x}, ${sum.y})") 
} 

class Point(val x: Int = 0, val y: Int = 10) { 

    // overloading plus function 
    operator fun plus(p: Point) : Point { 
        return Point(x + p.x, y + p.y) 
    } 
}
```

When you run the program, the output will be:

```
sum = (5, 1)
```

---

Specifically, the return line:
`return Point(x + p.x, y + p.y)`

How is this line working? Why is it `x + p.x` - where are those values coming from?

Comment: `p` is the `Point` parameter (and `p.x` therefore refers to the second operand's `x` value), where is the confusion?

Comment: The function only has 1 parameter (1 Point parameter) so I'm failing to see how the other Point instance is passed in.

Comment: The other instance is `this`; it's a member function.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. One last thing, what would happen if you return `return (x + p.x, y + p.y)`? Omitting the Point

Comment: That wouldn't be possible as Kotlin doesn't support tuples (and the return type is specified as `Point`, so you _have_ to return a `Point`; of course this doesn't mean that you couldn't make `plus` return an entirely different type.) While you can destructure a data class (e.g. `val (x, y) = point`) you cannot do the reverse (yet?)

Comment: Thanks. I've got another question: why is `var sum = Point()` needed? Isn't type Point implied?

Comment: It could have instead been `val sum = p1 + p2`, there is no need for an intermediate variable. `var sum = Point()` creates a point instance but since it is immediately reassigned the initial value is somewhat "point"less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class `class Point(val x: Int = 0, val y: Int = 10)` which has `x` and `y` properties. Consider `operator fun plus(p: Point) : Point` as a simple function of class `Point` that receives another `Point` as a parameter, creates another instance of `Point` adding `x` and `y` coordinates of current and another point `p` and returns it. So in that function you have access to the properties of current instance of `Point` and another `Point` instance: `x` and `y`.

We can read the expression `var sum: Point = p1 + p2` as the following:
take `p1` as a current instance of `Point`, add `p2` as another instance of `Point`. In this case `plus` function is called on the `p1` instance with passing `p2` as the argument of that function. When the function returns variable `sum` will refer to the instance of newly created `Point`.